# How do I pass a variable to use as the ODBC Source SQL Command for Teradata in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc, etl, teradata

I need to build a SELECT statement during the execution of an SSIS package to be used as the SQL command in an SSIS ODBC Source activity for a Teradata source.

The SELECT statement is built correctly, and all I need to do is assign it as the SQL command for the ODBC Source activity. I'm not looking to pass a variable as an argument to a query but to provide the entire SQL Command from a variable value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should open the ODBC Source component editor and set the data access mode to `SQL Command`.

[image]

Next, you should select the *Data FLow Task* and press F4 to show the properties tab. Then, go to the expression property and open the expression editor dialog.

You will note that there is a property called `ODBC Source.SQL Command` that you can evaluate as an expression.

[image]

You can use the variable when evaluating this property as an expression.

[image]

Comment: @JoeFoster If this answer solved the issue [feel free to accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)